# codeigniter where = does not work with words

Tags: php, codeigniter

The following code is not working properly:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT accountType FROM users WHERE id = $loggedID" );
```

It errors if the `$loggedID` is words like "justin", but if its only number like 201110523, it works. I don't know what is wrong. The datatype of the id in users is varchar.

```
public function account_type_student(){
    $loggedID = $this->input->post('id'); 

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT accountType FROM users WHERE id = $loggedID" );

    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
        $query = $row->accountType;
    }

    if($query=="student"){    
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;                  
        }                
    }
```

Comment: what error are you seeing?

Comment: Strings in SQL must be properly escaped and wrapped with quotation marks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it is a word / string like "justin" then you have to escape your variable:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT accountType FROM users WHERE id = '$loggedID' " );
```

Or use the active pattern syntax:

```
$this->db->select('accountType');
$this->db->where('id', $loggedID);
$query = $this->db->get('users');
```

Comment: @user3800149 if this helps then read here [**Accepting Answers: How does it work?**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)